# Why is this logical expression in python False?

Tags: python, expression

My question is, why are these expressions False?

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:45:15) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> num = raw_input("Choose a number: ")
Choose a number: 5
>>> print num
5
>>> print ( num < 18 )
False
>>> print ( num == 5 )
False
```

Because if i try this:

```
>>> print ( num > 0 )
True
```

The expression works fine.

Comment: just a note: if you did `num` instead of `print num` in your interactive console you would have noticed your mistake immediately because it would have printed `'5'` instead of `5`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This statement:

```
num = raw_input("Choose a number: ")
```

makes `num` a **string**, not a number, despite its misleading name.  It so happens that Python 2 lets you compare strings with numbers, and in your version considers all strings larger than all numbers (the *contents* of the string play no role).

Use `num = int(num)` to make an integer (and be sure to use a try/except to catch possible errors when the user has typed something other than a number!) before you start comparing.

(In Python 3, the function's name changes from `raw_input` to `input`, and it still returns strings; however in Python 3 comparing a string with a number is considered an error, so you would get an exception rather than `True` or `False` in each of your comparison attempts).

Answer (score 3):

The variable `num` does not actually contain the number `5`; it contains the string `"5"`. Because Python is strongly typed, `5 == "5"` is `False`. Try converting it to an integer first:

```
>>> print (int(num) < 18)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

`num` is a string. You can't meaningfully compare a string to an integer and a string is never equal to an integer (so == returns false and `<` and `>` return whatever they want). The reason that `<` and `>` don't throw an error (before python 3) when you compare strings and integers is to be able to sort heterogeneous lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try `num = float(raw_input("Choose..."))`

You're evaluating a string in your boolean expressions.